# How Charlie Wilson knows Gust listening at the door?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, charlie-wilsons-war

In *Charlie Wilson's War* (2007), there is a scene where Charlie questions Gust about listening to him at the door. Actually Charlie was talking to his assistants while at the same time Gust was waiting outside the closed door.

> Gust: Don't forget the limo driver.
>
> Charlie Wilson: What do you mean?
>
> Gust: Well, you took a limo from the casino to the airport. Maybe it's
>   easy enough to track down a limo driver, hand him a subpoena, ask him
>   if anything was going on in the back seat, so, you know, in terms of
>   cleaning up this...
>
> Charlie Wilson: Were you listening at the door?

There is no mention of **casino** or **limo driver** before, while Charlie was talking to his assistants then how Charlie Wilson knows Gust was listening at the door?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gust wasn't listening at the door**...he'd planted a listening device in Charlie's office.

When the first meet, Gust presents him with a bottle of scotch.

> Charlie, I wasn't standing at the door, don't be an idiot, I bugged the bottle.
>   The scotch.
>
> Yeah, it's got a little transmitter on it, I've got a thing in my ear.

[image]

> My question is how does Charlie know that Gust listening even before?

Because he was listening when Charlie mentioned being at a party in Vegas.

It's a safe assumption that this was in a **casino** and that a man of Charlie's stature would take a **limo** to the casino.

Your quote was slightly wrong, it's...

> Well, you took a limo from the casino to the airport **maybe**, it's easy enough to track down a limo driver

So he's posing a hypothetical situation, not stating a fact...and, as it turns out,...he was right.